# Как обойтись без переменной

Tags: ассемблер, masm32, masm

Как сделать invoke без создания переменной которая в дальнейшем мне больше не пригодится?

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 uselib masm32, comctl32, ws2_32 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
x dd ? 
y dd 6 
n dd ? 
m dd 5 


saida2 db "x = %d",0 ;Вот её бы хотелось бы убрать
 .code 

 start: 
   invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
push ebx 
mov ebx, n 
inc n 
.while m != ebx 
pop ebx 
mov eax, x 
add eax, y 
mov x, eax 
mov eax, x 
invoke crt_printf, offset saida2, dword ptr n ;Внимание
add esp,2*8
push ebx 
mov ebx, n 
inc n 
.endw 
 Main endp 

 end start
```

А хотелось бы вот так

```
.486 
 .model flat, stdcall 
 option casemap :none 
 __UNICODE__ equ 1 
 include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
 include C:\masm32\include\msvcrt.inc
 include C:\masm32\macros\macros.asm 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib 
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\msvcrt.lib
 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
 uselib masm32, comctl32, ws2_32 
 Main   PROTO 
 .data 
x dd ? 
y dd 6 
n dd ? 
m dd 5 

 .code 

 start: 
   invoke Main 
 invoke ExitProcess,0 
 Main proc 
push ebx 
mov ebx, n 
inc n 
.while m != ebx 
pop ebx 
mov eax, x 
add eax, y 
mov x, eax 
mov eax, x 
invoke crt_printf, ("repeat = %d",0), dword ptr n ;Внимание
add esp,2*8
push ebx 
mov ebx, n 
inc n 
.endw 
 Main endp 

 end start
```

Comment: Напишите свой макрос, который будет создавать ссылку и заполнять код сам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете, например, разместить строку в динамической памяти, и заполнить её посимвольно. А потом удалить её. Или в стеке. Это, однако, будет намного больше кода, чем сейчас, так что я бы не советовал особо заморачиваться.

Comment: Кажется, вот [релевантное обсуждение](https://forum.tuts4you.com/topic/19678-how-to-define-local-string-in-masm/).